# Window>arrange>tile not creating separate windows - illustrator CS6

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6

I have created a new window so I have 2 versions of my file to look at at the same time. I am wanting to have the windows appear like below.

[image: window split with two viewports open on separate versions of the same image]

However when I go to window>arrange>tile it doesn't create two separate windows like the above - it just creates a new tab.

[image: selecting window>tile]

[image: result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First**, if the desire is multiple windows tiled on screen, you can **not** use tabbed documents. At least not in CS6.

Tabs won't allow the creation of tillable windows, you can't tile tabs. So you first must navigate to `Illustrator > Preferences > User Interface` and **uncheck** `Open Documents as Tabs`. Or merely create floating windows of what you want tiled (In the Window Menu).

Then it's a two step processes to get a tiled windows for a single document.

1. Choose `Window > New Window`
2. Choose `Window > Arrange > Tile`

Simply choosing `Tile` does not open a *new* window.
`Tile` will merely tile *existing* windows (but again, it won't tile *tabs*).

---

In CS6 if you have the **Application bar** visible (`Window > Application bar`), you can merely choose one of the tiling options there and all the open tabs *or* windows will be tiled to match the icon.

I had 3 tabs, so I get options for layouts of up to 3. Tabs are auto-converted to floating windows then tiled.

[image]

To be blunt, this is really the **only** use for the Application Bar in CS6. You can open Adobe Bridge (the other icon seen in the screenshot above) via keyboard shortcuts if needed.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example using Illustrator CC, but as far as I remember it was the same in earlier versions.

You can click and drag tabs off the tab bar, and manually reposition and resize the document windows.

[image]